# about c# webrequest and website blocking me

Tags: c#, http, web, httpwebrequest, block

So i made a c# program that sends every 0.5 sec (changed it to every 30 sec now when i understood it stucked my internet) a request to a site (to get its html).

Now, even after i close the application the site just doesnt load up, it says that the site took to much time to respond...(all browsers) and its not that the website is gone if my friends try to enter, it works and even through proxy on my computer. could he somehow blocked me for to much requests? how can i enter it again?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: The site probably assumed you were DOSing and blocked you.  You may drop off the blocked list automatically after some time, but there really is no way to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, even after i close the application the site just doesnt load up,
>   it says that the site took to much time to respond...(all browsers)
>   and its not that the website is gone if my friends try to enter, it
>   works and even through proxy on my computer. could he somehow blocked
>   me for to much requests?

Well yes, your code basically simulates a [Denial of Service attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) - any decent provider will sooner or later block you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  There is no way to solve the problem without getting the owner to unblock you, or to change your IP address (which is what happens when you use a proxy).

You have now learned your lesson, don't do that to other peoples sites.  They get angry and block you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info, he had blocked me manually or its automatic? and now when i changed it to every 30 sec will he still block me (from another computer)? and if the website is blocked how should i contact him?